# How to export array values into different rows in CSV?

Tags: python

I'm trying to export rankings and URLs based on a specific keyword from Google and export it to a csv. Everything works fine except for the way my CSV file is composed.

My problem is that when I export my array to CSV, everything is on one row. I want it to be on 2 different columns and multiple rows.

I have tried adding `'\n'` inside the `rank` variable and it breaks the line in the terminal when I print the results, but inside the csv it appends the \n as a new value.

I tried adding `newline='\n'`to `open()` and it did break in the terminal but not in the csv export.

```py
d=[]
for i in links:
    counter = counter + 1
    if sitename in str(i):
        url = i.find_all('a', href=True)
        position = "position: %d" % (counter)
        rank = "url: %s" % (url[0]['href'])
        d.append(position)
        d.append(rank)
        print(position, rank)


filename = "rank_export.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "URL, Rank\n" 
f.write(headers)
f.write(str(d))
f.close()
```

Comment: We can convert to pandas, add headers and use ```python df.to_csv(index=False) ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are appending both the position and the rank in the same list. Then you are writing that list in the csv, and thus the one-line output. You are also trying to pass the csv headers using a comma-separated string instead of a list of column names;

The following should do the trick for you:

```
import csv

with open('rank_export.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['URL', 'Rank'])
    writer.writerows(zip(d[0::2], d[1::2]))
```